# Horizontal Scrolling of a div by javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a div in which there is a  table . The table has as many columns that there appears a horizontal scrollbar under it. I have to highlight a textbox which is at extream right and is not in the view port. How do I get that texbox in the viewport ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to highlight a textbox which is at extream right and is not in
>   the view port

```
textbox.focus()
```

should do